How to remove commands and desktop icon for an uninstalled program?
Im using ubuntu 22.04 desktop.
I mistakenly tried to install the alarm-clock-applet. After I discovered it didn't work, I removed the repository and purged it. I then went though the process of autoclean, clean, autoremove, and -f install, followed by a restart. Unfortunately, the desktop icon remains and the command "alarm-clock-applet" remains on my system. I tried the same steps above, this time with --remove --force-remove-reinstreq, I restarted and again the icon and command are both present. The PPA is removed, I check my bashrc and bashrc_profile and I cannot find reference to the "alarm-clock-applet" command, yet I keep getting the following error when I run the command:
alarm-clock-applet:ERROR:/home/user/alarm-clock-0.4.1/src/alarm-applet.c:319:alarm_applet_apps_load: assertion failed: (default_audio_app_item != NULL)
Bail out! alarm-clock-applet:ERROR:/home/user/alarm-clock-0.4.1/src/alarm-applet.c:319:alarm_applet_apps_load: assertion failed: (default_audio_app_item != NULL)
Aborted (core dumped)
I looked in my applications folder under my local files and I cannot find the document containing this icon either...
I have no idea where these files are hiding. Anyone have some insight as to how I can finish this uninstall?

As for the desktop-icon are you talking about side panel or app drawer??
If yes then you can check /usr/share/applications/ for any entries pertaining to alarm-clock-applet.
As for the alarm-clock-applet command entry still being present you can check /bin for any related entries.

Go to the directory
cd /usr/share/applications/

And remove the icon shortcut file something like alarm-clock-applet
rm -rf alarm-clock-applet.desktop

Search and check if there is left anything related to this program
find ~ -name "*alarm-clock-applet*"

Remove any unnecessary remainings
